# React Router not working Cannot GET /about

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Cannot understand why I cannot load about component or shop component when I go to localhost/about or localhost/shop respectively

```
    <Router>
        <div className="App">
            <Nav />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route path="/shop" component={Shop} />
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
```

Comment: try localhost:PORT/route like localhost:3000/shop

Answer (score 0):

localhost/about is an incorrect URL when you are working in localhost [if you don't use a default PORT]. it must be with your PORT like below.

```
localhost:3000/about
```